# how to fill and submit html text box's with python

Tags: python, html, web, python-requests, fill

is there a pythonic way to fill and submit a website's text box if i have the URL for the website and the id for the textbox

such as this one

`<input id="nickname">`

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You need the endpoint where the form is sent and send the data with the same params. As a recomendation try to right-click on button and inspect the url where the form is sent.